# Question pertaining to perfect powers in sums of consecutive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I came across this question in the book *Challenge and Thrill of Pre-college mathematics:*

> Prove that there are infinitely many sets of five consecutive integers $a,b,c,d,e$ such that $a+b+c+d+e$ is a perfect cube, and $b+c+d$ is a perfect square.

I took the numbers to be $(n-2),(n-1),n,(n+1),(n+2)$, and then it was not very difficult to find that what was required to prove was the existence of infinite numbers $n$ such that $5n$ and $3n$ are perfect cubes and squares respectively.

After playing around with prime factorizations for a while, I discovered that $675$ was such a number, followed by $3^9\cdot5^2$. Clearly this has something to do with the prime factorization of these integers.

Futhermore, I think it is correct to assume that that multiplying $675$ with any number $p^k$ where $p$ is a prime and where $k\mid3$ and $k\mid2$, such as multiplying by $2^{6}$, which gives us $43200$, which is indeed such a number.

My problem is that I have no idea how I am supposed to write such a proof formally, or even if this *is* a proof. While I do believe that I have generated an infinite number of positive integers which obey the question, how do I explain it? What am I missing?

Comment: My below answer is a different way to show that infinite many solutions exist, but your argument is perfectly right. You have found one solution and showed that we can multiply it how often we want with $64$ to get another solution. This clearly shows that infinite many solutions must exist.

Comment: Do you think you can extend this result to more primes?

Comment: Extend the $p^k$ result or to some integer $n$ where $pn$ and $qn$ are powers for prime $p$ and $q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find positive integers $n\ge 3$, such that $3n$ is a perfect square and $5n$ is a perfect cube.

Consider $$n=3^a\cdot 5^b$$ with positive integers $a$ and $b$. $3n$ is a perfect square, if $a$ is odd and $b$ is even. $5n$ is a perfect cube, if $a$ is divisible by $3$ and $b$ has the form $3k+2$. Hence, it is enough that $a$ is of the form $6s+3$ and $b$ of the form $6t+2$ , giving infinite many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You already have it all for demonstrating there are infinite such numbers.

$$n=675\cdot p^6$$
for primes $p>5$ already gives you infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You basically want infinitely many $n$ with $5n$ a perfect cube, and $3n$ a perfect square. Indeed, your last argument is enough to produce infinitely such $n$, since $n = 675p^{6l}$, for any prime(in fact any number) $p$ and any $l$ satisfies the given conditions. This is easy to see because :
$$
5n = 5 \times 675 p^{6l} = 5^33^3p^{6l} = (15p^{2l})^3 \quad ; \quad 3n = 3 \times 675 p^{6l} = 5^23^4p^{6l} = (45p^{3l})^2
$$

Since both $p$ and $l$ may infinitely vary, we see (from prime factorization) that we can produce infinitely many values of $n$, and hence infinitely many tuples $(a,b,c,d,e) = (n-2,n-1,n,n+1,n+2)$.